# Refresh in react page redirect it to /404 page

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have some routes in my react application and I describe that any url out of my routes redirect to /404 page , but it doesn't work correctly ;
when I refresh my page it redirects to /404 page and even when I want to go to / (home page) redirects to /404 to !  below is my routes :

```js
<Router>
      <Switch>
          <UserProvider>
             <PageLayout>
                <Route exact to="/" ><HomePage /></Route >
                <Route to="/product" ><Product /></Route >
                <Route to="/contactus" ><ContactUs /></Route >
                <Route to="/aboutus" ><AboutUs /></Route >
                <Route to="/404" ><NotFound /></Route >
                <Redirect from="/**/" to="/404" />
             </PageLayout >
          </UserProvider >
      </Switch>
</Router>
```

Can anyone say to me what is my problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route to="/" exact component={HomePage}/>
    <Route to="/product" exact component={Product}/>
    <Route to="/contactus" exact component={ContactUs}/>
    <Route to="/aboutus" exact component={AboutUs}/>
    <Route to="/*" exact component={NotFound}/>
  <Switch>
 <Router/>
```

Try this. I think it gonna work ;)

Comment: Thank you for your answer , but your solution did not work for me

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the below:

```
<Router>
      <Switch>
        ...
        <Redirect from="/**/" to="/404" />
      </Switch>
</Router>
```

You redirect the `/**/` to `/404`

Read this article [here](https://medium.com/@nikjohn/react-router-v4-redirecting-from-to-defaultpath-5bfcea9feed7)

Maybe you should do it like that:

Change `/**/` with `*` and rearrange your routes as:

```
<Router>
      <Switch>
        ...
        <Redirect from="*" to="/404" />
        <Route to="/404" ><NotFound /></Route >
      </Switch>
</Router>
```

Or you can just use (**if React version >= 4**)

```
<Redirect to="/404" />
```

The React Router Documentation [here](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Redirect)

Comment: Thanks for your anwser,I tried your solution but in general, it did not show the 404 page anymore

Comment: I updated my answer. I forgot to rearrange your routes. The order matters here.